# DHTMLX scheduler timeline horizontal scrolling

Tags: jquery, css, scheduler, dhtml, dhtmlx-scheduler

I've read in this posts that the Horizontal Scrolling feature in DHTMLX Scheduler.NET (MVC ver.) is not possible as of now. (until version 5 as per 2nd link.)

http://forum.dhtmlx.com/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=29786&start=0

http://forum.dhtmlx.com/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=33332

Does anybody has a work around/hack on this? I need this working because I have to show 24 hours but that will shrink every cell.

I tried manipulating it with CSS with no luck because almost all of its elements has static width when the scheduler was rendered.

Anyone has an idea? Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a code sample you can provide? I'm trying to figure out where to point you, but I'm not sure how similar your code is to the samples. I'm using the sample under `samples/06_timeline/03_tree.html`, so if that's similar enough to what you're trying to do, then I can go ahead and take a stab at an answer.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, @NJP. My code is similar to this example: http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/samples/06_timeline/02_lines.html.

Answer (score 0):

With the new version 6.0.0, they've added the `scrollable` (true or false) option.

```
scheduler.createTimelineView({
        name: "timeline",
        fit_events: true,
        section_autoheight: true,
        x_unit: "hour",
        x_date: "%H:%i",
        x_step: 6,
        x_size: 24,
        x_start: 0,
        x_length: 4,
        y_unit: sections,
        y_property: "sectionID",
        render: "bar",  
        event_dy: "full",
        scrollable: false,  //<-- set to false
        second_scale: {
            x_unit: "day",
            x_date: "%D, %F %d"
        }
    });
```

More here:
https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/api__scheduler_createtimelineview.html